# Get specific data after output everything from database

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, html-table, row

I've got here a table with all the data from my database. On the end on every row, I have put a checkbox with the value 1, to update the 'accept' status in my database, which is default by 0.

**My problem is, that the value of a ticked checkbox should update the 'accept' status ONLY in the entry in its row after the submit button got pressed.**

So basically I need to check if the checkbox is ticked, and if its ticked, the 'accept' status in the row of the checkbox gets the value of 1. For that, I think I need to get the 'match_id' of the row.

This is how it looks on the website:

[image: http://imgur.com/lPKgIax]

This is the table:

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('lr') or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `challenge`") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table class='match-table'>";
      echo "<thead><tr> <th><h1>match_id</h1></th> <th><h1>Team</h1></th><th><h1>Accept Status</h1></th><th><h1>Accept</h1></th> </tr></thead><tbody>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr><td>"; 
        echo $row['match_id'];
          echo "</td><td>"; 
        echo $row['team'];
          echo "</td><td>";
        echo $row['accept'];
          echo "</td><td>";
      ?>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="challenge_accept" value="1"/>
      <?php   
        echo "</td></tr>";  
      }
      echo "</tbody></table>";
            ?>
      <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
      <input type="reset" value="Delete"/>
      </form>
```

Any suggestions how I can do that?

Comment: you can perform the ajax post request and then update your database row-wise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is utterly invalid, with MULTIPLE `<form>` being opened and only one `</form>` at the end of the page. You're also splitting your tags into garbage like

```
<tr><td><form></td></tr>
[many repeats]
</table>
</form>
```

Your form fields also don't include ANY method of identifying which row was actually clicked on, e.g. `<input type="submit" name="selected_row" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" />`. As it stands right now, you've hardcoded the value `1`, so no matter which of however many buttons you spit out, they'll ALL be sending `1` back to your code.

Comment: so I can identify which row was actually clicked on with the mysql_fetch_row function, or is there a better solution?

Comment: not with fetch_row(), but you do need to embed something into each row's button, like I showed above.